# Mocking a concrete class using EasyMock

Tags: java, easymock

Is it possible to mock a concrete class using EaskMock? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the [EasyMock Class Extension](http://easymock.org/EasyMock2_2_2_ClassExtension_Documentation.html) documentation and [download it from the SourceForge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/easymock/files/). You can't mock final methods though.

EDIT: This is now part of EasyMock for v3 and above, as noted in comments.

Comment: It should be noted that the new versions of EasyMock (>= 3.0) include this extension, as Mike Partridge noted in another answer here.

Answer (score 7):

[Powermock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) extends EasyMock and allows you to mock concrete types, even final and static methods.

> PowerMock is a framework that extend other mock libraries such as EasyMock with more powerful capabilities. PowerMock uses a custom classloader and bytecode manipulation to enable mocking of static methods, constructors, final classes and methods, private methods, removal of static initializers and more.

Answer (score 3):

Yes: http://easymock.org/EasyMock2_4_ClassExtension_Documentation.html

Answer (score 3):

EasyMock class extensions have been integrated into EasyMock as of v3.0; see [the release notes](http://easymock.org/EasyMock3_0_Documentation.html).

Answer (score 0):

When creating a mock, simply use the **org.easymock.classextension** version of the EasyMock class. The result will be castable.

Here's a recent link - http://easymock.org/EasyMock3_2_ClassExtension_Documentation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can mock an object using 'PowerMock.createMock' method. Reference [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2017/06/powermock-easymock-mock-object.html).

Example

```
File file = PowerMock.createMock(File.class);
                
EasyMock.expect(file.getName()).andReturn("TestFile");
EasyMock.expect(file.getAbsolutePath()).andReturn("/Users/HariKrishna/TestFile");
```

If you want to partially mock some of the methods, you can use 'PowerMock.createPartialMock' method. Reference [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2017/07/powermock-easymock-partially-mock-object.html).

Example

```
EmployeeService empService = PowerMock.createPartialMock(EmployeeService.class, "getEmployeeFirstNames");
EasyMock.expect(empService.getEmployeeFirstNames(emps)).andReturn(empNames);
```

Refer this [tutorial](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2017/06/easymock-powermock-tutorial.html) for more examples.