# Why junit test failed when creating mock with EasyMock.createMock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, sockets, junit, easymock

I am experiencing unexpected behavior of EasyMock when writing junit test. Finally, I deleted some lines of code until there is one line of creating mock left to see what happened.

```
@Test
public void testSimple() throws Exception {
    Socket socket = EasyMock.createMock(Socket.class);
}
```

This junit test generates error:

```
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0.052 sec
```

This is not the case when I just have normal instantiation like:

```
@Test
public void testSimple() throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
}
```

This junit test seems happy with that:

```
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.047 sec
```

I wonder if someone can clear this ambiguity. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any exception in the case "EasyMock"?

Comment: I also think this happens because a exception is thrown.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mocking a concrete class using easymock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249317/mocking-a-concrete-class-using-easymock)

Answer (score 4):

You're attempting to make a mock of a concrete class (Socket is not an interface), so you probably need to do a little extra work.

Assuming you are using 3.X version of EasyMock, you likely need to add the other libraries required for class mocking:

> cglib (2.2) and Objenesis (1.2) must be in the classpath to perform class mocking

Comment: As of EasyMock 3.0 (3.4 now) you don't need to specify `cglib` or `Objenesis`.  Mocking classes just works.

Answer (score 3):

If you are mocking concrete classes you need to use EasyMock Class Extension

http://easymock.org/EasyMock2_2_2_ClassExtension_Documentation.html

Link shows how.
http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-do-i-mock-a-concrete-class-using-easymock

Answer (score 2):

As of EasyMock 3.0 (the current version is 3.2), you can mock concrete classes so you would not get this error now.